# Synapse/Data Factory Sharepoint Online List connector

Tags: azure-data-factory, sharepoint-online, azure-synapse

I have trouble getting the Sharepoint Online List connector in Data Factory to work, I have followed the guide provided by Microsoft on this step-by-step three times: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sharepoint-online-list , but to no luck. I have added all sharepoint site permission in the AAD-app but still getting the following error when I test the connection through the linked service:

Failed to get metadata of odata service, please check if service url and credential is correct and your application has permission to the resource. Expected status code: 200, actual status code: Unauthorized, response is : {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Token type is not allowed."}.

I have also tried creating an app directly in Sharepoint to to this, still no luck. Any ideas what this problem is?

Answer (score 0):

The possible cause is that the service principal or managed identity you use doesn't have permission to access the certain folder/file. **Please grant corresponding permissions on all the folders and subfolders you need to copy**

To use managed identities for Azure resources authentication, follow these steps:

**Step1:**  Retrieve the data factory managed identity information by copying the value of the "Service Identity Application ID" generated along with your factory.

**Step2:**  Grant the managed identity access to Data Lake Store. See examples on how permission works in Data Lake Storage Gen1 from Access control in Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1.

•   `As source`: In Data explorer > Access, grant at least Execute permission for ALL upstream folders including the root, along with Read permission for the files to copy. You can choose to add to This folder and all children for recursive, and add as an access permission and a default permission entry. There's no requirement on account-level access control (IAM).

•   `As sink`: In Data explorer > Access, grant at least Execute permission for ALL upstream folders including the root, along with Write permission for the sink folder. You can choose to add to This folder and all children for recursive, and add as an access permission and a default permission entry.